# MATLAB contour sharp corners

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

MATLAB contour plots appear to round corners, even when they should not be rounded.

In the plot

```
num_incs = 1000;
x = linspace(-1,1,num_incs);
[Xa,Ya] = meshgrid(x,x);
Z = abs(Xa) + abs(Ya);

contour(Xa,Ya,Z,20,'LineWidth',4);
```

[image: one-norm plot]

the corners are rounded. Is there a way to turn off automatic rounding in order to make the corners "sharp"?

I've tried changing the [renderer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rendererinfo.html), but to no affect. Also, turning off graphics smoothing with

`set(gcf,'GraphicsSmoothing','off');`
does not produce sharp corners.

EDIT:
Note that on Matlab 2020b with `num_incs = 1001` (or `3`),
I still get rounded corners:
[image]

EDIT 2:
I'm trying to access and modify the LineJoin property:

```
num_incs = 3;
x = linspace(-1,1,num_incs);
[Xa,Ya] = meshgrid(x,x);
Z = abs(Xa) + abs(Ya);

[C,hContour] = contour(Xa,Ya,Z,20,'LineWidth',4);

drawnow;
for i = 1:length(hContour.EdgePrims)
    hContour.EdgePrims(i).LineJoin = deal('miter');
    hContour.EdgePrims(i).LineWidth = 1; % to see what is being adjusted
end
```

but this only affects the "outer" lines. This approach was inspired by [this post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/customizing-contour-plots).

### Conclusion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68533356/3385432

Comment: Reduce the line width, you'll get less corner rounding.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I am making a presentation and thinner lines aren't visible when projected.

Comment: Then why do you worry about the corners on the lines? Those won’t be visible either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`LineJoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html#bubwqbv-1_sep_shared-LineJoin) property of the lines to `'miter'` to get sharp corners:

```
[C,h] = contour(Xa,Ya,Z,20, 'LineWidth',4);
draw now
set(h.EdgePrims,'LineJoin','miter')
```

By default this property is `'round'`.

But be aware that the sharp corners produced can be unreasonably long, depending on the angle between the two lines meeting, and leading to misinterpretation of the data. A third option is `'chamfer'`, which gives sharp corners but cuts them off if they become too large.

Comment: This is very close! But it doesn't appear that `'LineJoin` can be used with contour: `Unrecognized property LineJoin for class Contour.`

Comment: @jmlarson: You've already found how to set the line properties in the contour object. What do you mean by *"outer" lines*? When I do `set(hContour.EdgePrims,'LineJoin','miter')` it sets the property for all the lines in the contour plot.

Comment: On 2020b, I get the behavior I mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503555/matlab-edgeprims-inaccesible-for-some-edges

Answer (score 1):

The choice of renderer may affect how the antialiasing will be applied to the drawn lines, but in your case the rounded corner effect is simply because no data is defined at the coordinates which should be the actual corners.

If you zoom in on any of your "corners", you'll notice that there is no point defined for all the `x=0` points, (nor for all the `y=0`). To overcome that, Matlab draws a line between the two closest defined points:

[image: corner not defined]

This is because of the way you define your grid. By choosing an even number of points (you chose 1000) over an interval, you can never have a point defined right at the center of the interval. To have the center point of the interval defined, you have to use an **odd** number of points.

The table below show the grid `Ya` close to the transition. You'll notice that the values go from negative to positive but there is no point defined at `y=0`:

[image: table]

To demonstrate without having to zoom in too much, we can use a lower number of points. Observe the difference between the 2 graphs below, they use the same code except for the first line. On the left I have used `num_incs = 10;`, while on the right I used `num_incs = 11;`:

[image: odd and even]

---

So in your case, use `num_incs = 1001;` and your corners should diseapear. Or if your example was actually your case use, notice that for such a simple shape you can get exactly the same visual result with `num_incs = 3;`. This only defines the necessary *corner* points, which are the start and stop of each line (and do not use the unnecessary intermediate points on a line).

[image: simplest]