# Hidden contour property EdgePrims inaccessible for some edges

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to change `LineJoin` for some lines in a MATLAB contour plot. When I modify the `EdgePrims`, only the "partial lines" are affected:

```
num_incs = 3;
x = linspace(-1,1,num_incs);
[Xa,Ya] = meshgrid(x,x);
Z = abs(Xa) + abs(Ya);

[C,hContour] = contour(Xa,Ya,Z,20,'LineWidth',4);

drawnow;
set(hContour.EdgePrims, 'LineStyle', 'dotted')
set(hContour.EdgePrims, 'LineJoin', 'miter')
drawnow;
```

produces the following:
[image]

That is, I am setting the `LineStyle` and `LineJoin` only on the outer edges. How can I access the line properties of the middle lines as well?

Comment: Maybe because they’re closed polygons they’re now stored in `FacePrims`? I have an older version of MATLAB that doesn’t do this, they’re all `EdgePrims`.

Comment: In 2020b, FacePrims are empty. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I have R2017a. I should upgrade one of these days. :) Anyway, it's was a guess. There must be some other hidden property that stores the closed polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new hidden property for the contour object (`matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Contour`): `EdgeLoopPrims`. This one contains handles to all the edges that form closed loops. `EdgePrims` now contains only handles to the lines that don't form a closed loop.

```matlab
set(hContour.EdgePrims, 'LineStyle', 'dotted')
set(hContour.EdgeLoopPrims, 'LineStyle', 'dotted')
```

As always with undocumented properties, this is bound to change at some point. Using this will limit your code use to specific versions of MATLAB. I tested this with R2021a.

---

To explore hidden properties, simply convert the graphics handle to a struct: `struct(hContour)`.